# How to fix Accessibility level A and AA errors

Tags: accessibility

Most of the sites are aiming for accessibility compliance these days. I installed google chrome Wave tool to check Level A and AA errors on my site. I see some errors like below for which I do not seem to have exact solution to fix.

1.Structural Elements | An unordered (bulleted) list ( element) is present.

2.Contrast Errors | Very low contrast between foreground and background colors.

3.Features | Alternative text is present for an image that is within a link.

4.ARIA | An aria-label or aria-labelledby attribute is present.

5.Structural Elements | A  element or navigation landmark is present.

6.Structural Elements | A  element or main landmark is present.

If I try to replace ul with ol, it gives me error like 'An ordered (bulleted) list ( element) is present.'

Rendering your navigation as plain links does not provide any semantic meaning; it would suggest that your navigation is a sentence to be read. By providing your links in a list, you supply a hint as to how we are to interpret this series of hypertext-linked words.(Reference link: [Unordered lists and accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310376/unordered-lists-and-accessibility))

Then how do we fix such errors?

**UPDATE**
Currently my code looks like

```
<ul class="header links">
<li>
<a href="https://base_url/customer/account/create/">Create Account</a></li>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
<a href="https://base_url/customer/account/login/referer/">Log in</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Structural elements]

If you look at the left sidebar of the screenshot, you see level A error.

Comment: You need to include the relevant HTML that the checker is complaining about. My guess is you are adding `<ul>` but not wrapping links in `<li>` from the information provided but at the moment it is impossible to tell. Also navigation should sit within the semantic `<nav>` element in HTML5. Please add detail to your question so we can help you, as it stands I have marked the question as "requires detail or clairty" but I will remove that vote if you make the ammends and then we can help you.

Comment: That looks fine so the error isn't my first suggestion, could copy the exact error message as it is now pointing me to my second thought I mentioned which is that it is complaining about links not being within a landmark (such as `<nav>`). Retracted close vote btw.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I have added screenshot for your reference. BDW, adding <nav> did not help.

Comment: sorry bud, that just shows advice, it isn't an error, is the page publicly available I am happy to jump on and have a look for you so I can clear all of this up.